# Bash Scripting, send "logout" command being skipped during ssh session

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

Essentially I connect to remote host, authenticate, run command, logout.  However logout command is being skipped.

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
spawn ssh $_host

expect "Password: ";
send "$_pass\r";

expect "$_host>";
send "sh arp | inc $_host2\r";

expect "$_host>";
send "logout\r";

EOD

echo "blah blah"
```

What i get is my expected output from arp command however, blah blah will be entered into the terminal of the remote host.  It seems the logout command is being skipped, somewhat new to bash scripting but it seems that expect doesn't instantly see "$_host>" when executing and skips it?  Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: (BTW, is there a shell script named `arp` in the remote home directory? `sh arp` is a rather unusual construct).

Comment: The idea behind using expect was that I would be able to reference expect_out(Buffer) to pass the output into a variable that I could thing manipulate to only capture the returned MAC address.  Also, had many issues with sshpass when using a variable, and only found success with a file, which I didn't like the security risk of.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the aforementioned issues, if you have any separate questions covering them.

Comment: @Charles Duffy yes, this is being ran against an aggregate router running Cisco IOS.

Comment: To be clear, `expect <<EOD` actually **does write your password to a file** already; it implicitly creates a file with your heredoc's contents in your temporary directory, and passes that filename on the stdin to the `expect` command.

Comment: (Hmm. The use of IOS actually *does* have some potential impact, though -- not all embedded SSH servers handle [`exec_command()`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command)/[`Run()`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Run) [giving the remote server a single command to run, which is what happens when you're passing a command to OpenSSH on the command line] and `invoke_shell()` [creating an interactive session] identically).

Comment: ...frankly, though, when I need precise control at the protocol level, I usually reach for [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) or [Go crypto/ssh](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) rather than the OpenSSH command line.

Comment: Company standards don't even really like scripted access to terminal tbh, working on seeing if logout works with sshpass and excluding expect all together.

Comment: assigning $_pass as an env var using -e worked like a charm, much appreciated.  I would sidebar to chat about passing this output to a variable now that I am no longer using except buffer however my SO rep is apparently inferior haha.

Comment: If you're really collecting stdout, `out=$(cmd)` is the usual pattern -- if you encapsulate your code in a function, `output=$(thatfunction)` is a good place to start. (If you're getting output written to the TTY rather than to a variable, the likely conclusion is that it's going to stderr rather than stdout, and `2>&1` is likely to be helpful). If the above notes don't help, feel free to ask a new question and @-notify me with a link to it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `expect` here at all. Even if you *must* get the password from a variable, using `sshpass` for the purpose will avoid mixing two separate languages (bash and TCL).

```
SSHPASS="$_pass" sshpass -e "$_host" "sh arp | inc $_host2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `\r` ( carrige return ) should be `\n` ( enter / new line ) ?

`send "logout\r";` -> `send "logout\n";`

If that will help - I would replace it in the entire script ..

Suggesting:

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
match_max 1000000

spawn ssh $_host

expect "Password: ";
send "$_pass\n";

expect "$_host>";
send "sh arp | inc $_host2\n";

expect "$_host>";
send "logout\n";

EOD

echo "blah blah"
```

Comment: I've tried that thinking the same thing however it still does not execute.

Comment: @HaydenSmith have you tried `exit` vs `logout` ? as far as I know an issue with one of the commands will simply be skipped and the issue is with the language `expect` not `bash`

Comment: Yes, both execute properly in a non scripted session, however do not work in the format provided.  Sorry should have listed things I've tried but wanted to keep it short and sweet.

Comment: @HaydenSmith in addition, I'm not sure how long the output from the `sh arp` command, but if it is long - try adding at the top of the script `match_max 1000000`

Comment: No cigar.  arp resolves very quickly maybe half a second max on average?

Comment: @HaydenSmith if you remove the `expect "$_host>"; && send "sh arp | inc $_host2\n";` does the `logout` work ok ?

Comment: No, it does not actually.

Comment: Then are you sure you're passing the password ? try w/o a space at the end and w/o big P something like `expect "assword:";`

Comment: Device cannot be accessed without valid credentials and I am able to both run arp command as well as echo my blah blah into devices terminal.